# Regular expression in bash s character

Tags: regex, bash

I have very strange issue with s character. 
This works:

```
[[ "import scala" =~ ^import\s*.+cala$ ]] && echo "yes"
```

but this doesn't work:

```
[[ "import scala" =~ ^import\s*scala$ ]] && echo "yes"
```

I tried to escape s and but it didn't works. 
How to solve this issue?

Comment: The first works because the `\s` is matched zero times (bash interprets this as a simple `s`), followed by `.` one or more times (here, it matches `_s` - that is, "_space, s_")... the second doesn't work because (as pointed out below) `\s` doesn't work in bash regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\s` doesn't work with bash regex. Use `[[:blank:]]` instead to match a space or tab character:

```
[[ "import scala" =~ ^import[[:blank:]].*scala$ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

PS: However `[[:space:]]` is equivalent of `\s` that also matches `\n`

Also note that you must use `.*` instead of `.+` before `scala` to match 0 or more characters instead of 1+ because space has already been matched using `[[:blank:]]`

Comment: On my PC - GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release first version works properly. The problem is with s character.

Comment: Check updated, I had a typo and missed `s` from `scala`. Note that it should be `.*` before not `.+` because space has already been matched.

Comment: @GeorgiNaumov In your first version, the `\s*` doesn't match anything; the `.+` matches the space and the `s` in `scala`. `bash` interprets `\s` as an unnecessarily escaped `s`; that is, `\s` matches the character `s`. (That is, what Attie said in a comment on the question itself a minute faster.)

Comment: prefer this `^import[[:blank:]]+scala$`?

Comment: @Attie: Yes `^import[[:blank:]]+scala$` is better if only spaces are allowed before `scala`

Answer (score 1):

\s will lose its meaning in shell (escaped as 's'), try to use a variable to store regex expression as suggested in bash manual:

```
ex='^import\s+scala$'; [[ "import scala" =~ $ex ]] && echo "yes"
```

This works on my machine.